# Creating flag column

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to ask you for your help. I want to create a flag column, that will mark specific contract numbers whith 1, where the "CLOSED" column is empty in some rows.

I tried

```
case when CLOSED is null then 1 else 0 end as flag
group by CONTRACT_NUMBER
```

but it's not working. Thank you for your responses

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiZ0P.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure closed column is null? maybe it's empty string ... try selecting first `select * from YourTable where NVL(Closed, '') = ''`

Comment: @Veljko89 - null and empty string are equivalent in Oracle. (Currently, if you believe what they've ben saying for, oh, 20-odd years about is changing one day, maybe).

Comment: Please post text not images. What does 'not working' mean? The image you posted shows the flags you seem to expect; if that isn't what you get then edit your question to show the sample data, data types, your current query and the actual output you get from it. (All as text...)

Comment: @AlexPoole wasn't aware of that, just did a test case and wow ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need analytic `max()` here:

**<sup>[demo](http://rextester.com/ZJKOIX36315)</sup>**

```
select t.*, 
       max(case when closed is null 
                then 1 
                else 0 
           end) over (partition by contract_number) as flag
  from t
```